# Can I transform this in list comprehension? (or make this code faster?)

Tags: python

This code takes a list of a and b and creates sequences of a and b. In each sequence can be x numbers of a and x numbers of b, but is not possible to have a letter to divide the other (aaabb is allowed but not aaba). Is it possible to transform this in a list comprehension?

```
 list_of_strings=["abaababbaabaaabbabbab","abbabbbabbbaa"]

final_list=[]
for elt in list_of_strings:
    final_list.append([])
    is_a=0
    for idx in range(1,len(elt)):
        if elt[idx] < elt[idx-1]: #try to find the index where a 'b' is followed by a 'a'
            final_list[-1].append(elt[is_a:idx]) #add the segment on the sublist of final_list. idx (correspond to a new 'a') is not include
            is_a=idx #the begin of next segment is the index of the new 'a'
    final_list[-1].append(elt[is_a:idx+1]) #finish with the lasts 'a' on the string
print(final_list)
```

Honestly I just need to make it faster, any other tip is welcomed.

I can't import any libreries.

Comment: Could a string start with "b"? If so, what should the result be for "babab"?

Comment: The result should ["be","ba","ba","a"]

Comment: That result makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emulating what your solution does, splitting when "b" changes to "a":

```
>>> [s.replace('ba', 'b a').split() for s in list_of_strings]
[['ab', 'aab', 'abb', 'aab', 'aaabb', 'abb', 'ab'],
 ['abb', 'abbb', 'abbb', 'aa']]
```

Comment: What if I wanted to do the same thing but with vowels and not vowels? Would be possible to use the same structure?

Comment: by the way great approach! Was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @KrankenWagen Hmm, no, I don't see a good way to generalize this for sets like vowels / non-vowels. Would have to go through all combinations. Doable, but not good.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The coding community is amazing, I've started to code in python less than one month ago and I'm recieving a lot of inputs from you all.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a regex might be a better fit here. This looks for one or more `a` characters followed by zero or more non-`a`s:

```
import re

list_of_strings=["abaababbaabaaabbabbab","abbabbbabbbaa"]

[re.findall(r'a+[^a]*', s) for s in list_of_strings]

# [['ab', 'aab', 'abb', 'aab', 'aaabb', 'abb', 'ab'],
#  ['abb', 'abbb', 'abbb', 'aa']]
```

---

**Edit based on comment**

Another way to do this that doesn't involve `re` is to `zip()` the strings with themselves at an offset of one. This allows you to avoid the complicated indexing and gives you a sliding window of letter pairs.

```
list_of_strings=["abaababbaabaaabbabbab","abbabbbabbbaa"]

def get_sets(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        yield s
        return
    current = ''
    for m,n in zip(s, s[1:]):
        current += m
        if m == 'b' and n == 'a':
            yield current
            current = ''
    yield current + n


[list(get_sets(s)) for s in list_of_strings]
```

Same result:

```
[['ab', 'aab', 'abb', 'aab', 'aaabb', 'abb', 'ab'],
 ['abb', 'abbb', 'abbb', 'aa']]
```

Comment: Forgot to specify, I can't import any libreries. The project is 100% "libreries free"

Comment: Yeah, now gets that case right. I wouldn't yield an empty string for empty input string, although the OP's does, too. Btw, I think all our solutions get "babab" wrong.